# How can I prevent Safari from removing first words of tabs' titles?

Tags: safari, tabs

Safari has a feature which removes duplicate first words of page titles from tabs, which is useful when sites' pages all begin with the same word or two. "Site Title | Page title 1" and "Site Title | Page title 2" show up as "Page title 1" and "Page title 2," for instance.

However, this can be annoying when two pages have the same first word, but are different, such as the two Ask Different pages, "Ask Different chat - chat.stackexchange.com" and "Ask a Question - Apple - Stack Exchange." These become "Different chat […]" and "a Question […]," which isn't very smart of Safari.

Is there any way I can control this to whatever extent possible?

Comment: Hi, is your question still valid?

Comment: @myhd I'm not sure…I don't think so, but maybe.
I don't know when it decides to truncate now, but the example posed in the question is no longer an issue. If I visit two questions on AD whose first tag is the same, Safari will helpfully remove it, but if I visit "Ask a Question" and "Ask Different", it does not (helpfully).
Regardless, it might be worth keeping to see if there's a way to turn it off entirely, not just to prevent erroneous behavior from occurring.

Comment: What version of safari are you using? It doesn't seem to happen with safari 8.0.6. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/KxTUxpp.png

Comment: @nelson2tm Hm, doesn't seem to be happening for me either. Maybe it has been removed entirely.

Comment: It only happens when there are too many tabs or the window size is small enough that truncation needs to occur. It still happens in Safari 9. (cc @nelson2tm)

Comment: I dont know of any way to control it, but you can hover over any tab to see the full name. and if you move your mouse directly to another tab, it will show you the title of that tab as well (with no delay, so even though it seems like it might be easier to just click the tab than wait for the tooltip to appear, if you want to see the titles of multiple tabs just wait for the first tool tip then slide over and the tool tip will change instantly).

Answer (score 1):

According to this [macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070418084404948) article I don't believe that there is a fix yet (if you really want this fixed, you could try searching for terminal commands to fix or disable this feature). Otherwise you could try switching browsers...

> When you use tabs, Safari sets the tab's title to include the domain name as well as the page title. For instance, macosxhints.com - Submit a Hint. However, when you have more than one or two tabs opened on the same site, Safari drops the domain name from all the tabs, and just includes the page title: Submit a Hint

Comment: Just sending people to an external site without clear indication of which extension you had in mind isn't very helpful. Can you add some details about the extension which will solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: Okay, will fix...